# AMPscript - Is it possible to do a Lookup that has a fallback written in?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

Basically, I have this, which works fully:

```
%%[
SET @StoreName = Lookup("ent.TopStore_List","Store Name","Store Number",[Store_To_Contact])
SET @StoreName = TRIM(@StoreName)
]%%
```

But is there a way that I can tell it that, if the Store_to_Contact field is blank, to instead reference another one?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You'll just need to use [**LookupRows()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) and check the [**rowcount()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/rowcount.htm).

```
%%[

var @rows, @row, @rowCount
var @storeToContact, @defaultStore, @StoreName
set @storeToContact = AttributeValue("Store_To_Contact")
set @defaultStore = AttributeValue("Default_Store") /* or whatever */

set @rows = LookupRows("ent.TopStore_List","Store Name", @storeToContact)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  set @row = row(@rows,1) /* get row #1 */
  set @StoreName  = field(@row,"StoreName ")

else

    set @rows = LookupRows("ent.TopStore_List","Store Name", @defaultStore)
    set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

    if @rowCount > 0 then

      set @row = row(@rows,1) /* get row #1 */
      set @StoreName  = field(@row,"StoreName ")

    else

      set @StoreName  = "DEFAULT STORE NOT FOUND"

    endif

endif 

]%%
<br>Store Name: %%=v(@storeName)=%%
```

I have several other lookup examples [**here on my blog**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).